# Download a file from restAPI using Azure Data Factory into Data lake

Tags: rest, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

Need some guidance or suggestion

Scenario:
We are trying fetch a file using RestAPI and save it to Azure Data Lake.

Journey:
Login, GetToken, Invoke GetFile API, and save to AzureDataLake

We are trying 2 options

1. using LogicApp-- this work fine, but apparently this is not approved PaaS service.
2. Using Data Factory-- here we are facing some issue. We are able to invoke the RestEndpoint, but unable to parse the response into a file (pdf, img etc...). How can I achieve this?

Best,
Ashwin

Comment: Hi @Ashwinkumar Iyer. Please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer. :)

Comment: Hi @JosephXu, apologies for coming late. Your understand is correct.
I have the filename in the header, and the content in the body, something like below
{
  "$content-type": "application/pdf",
  "$content": "JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjE0IDAgb2JqDTw8L0xpbmVhcml6ZWQgMS9MIDQ3OTgxL08gMTYvRSA0MzUzMy9OIDEvVCA0NzY3OC9IIFsgNDY5IDE2Ml0+Pg1lbmRv"
}
I want to extract the content, and place it in PDF. The file name I want to extract from header.

Comment: Hi @Ashwinkumar Iyer  I think you’d better clarify your question or start another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change to use **HTTP connector** :

**HTTP connector** is generic to retrieve data from any HTTP endpoint, for example, to **download files**.

**REST connector**  is used to copy the REST JSON response.
You can refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/connector-rest)